# how to add a day to a date using jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have 2 textboxes on my site for pickup date and drop off date both using the jquery date picker.

I am having trouble setting the drop off date value to be one day ahead of the pickup date that was selected.

Here is what I have:

```
$('.pickupDate').change(function() {
    var date2 = $('.pickupDate').datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
    $('.dropoffDate').datepicker('setDate', date2);
});
```

The above will execute but the value in the drop off textbox will match the pickup value instead of being one day ahead. eg: if I select 01-01-2010 the above code returns 01-01-2010 in the drop off box instead of 02-01-2010.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for your help,
Rich

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('.pickupDate').change(function() {
  var date2 = $('.pickupDate').datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1); 
  $('.dropoffDate').datepicker('setDate', date2);
});
```

Comment: The above works for me too. But why the "+1d" part in line 2? I removed "+1d" from the second line and it works too.

Comment: great solution, tried 10 other ways to increment date in javascript and none worked.

Comment: @thd '+1d' in line 2 did not need [Datepicker getDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)

Comment: Do you know why if trying to simplify merging the third and fourth lines into something like `$('.dropoffDate').datepicker('setDate', date2.getDate()+1);` it fails and adds 2 days instead of 1? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/507Lwkeb/

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro  What you can do is `$('.dropoffDate').datepicker('setDate', "+1d");`. See the setDate documentation for other options [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie I would need for 10 days ? which script i need to change then?

Comment: The line `date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);` can be modified to `date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+10);`

Comment: Use `this` object instead of selecting again (`.pickupDate`). like: 
`var date2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');`

Answer (score 10):

This answer really helped me get started (noob) - but I encountered some weird behavior when I set a start date of 12/31/2014 and added +1 to default the end date. Instead of giving me an end date of 01/01/2015 I was getting 02/01/2015 (!!!). This version parses the components of the start date to avoid these end of year oddities.

---

```
 $( "#date_start" ).datepicker({

   minDate: 0,
   dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",

   onSelect: function(selected) {
         $("#date_end").datepicker("option","minDate", selected); //  mindate on the End datepicker cannot be less than start date already selected.
         var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
         var tempStartDate = new Date(date);
         var default_end = new Date(tempStartDate.getFullYear(), tempStartDate.getMonth(), tempStartDate.getDate()+1); //this parses date to overcome new year date weirdness
         $('#date_end').datepicker('setDate', default_end); // Set as default                           
   }

 });

 $( "#date_end" ).datepicker({

   minDate: 0,
   dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",

   onSelect: function(selected) {
     $("#date_start").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected); //  maxdate on the Start datepicker cannot be more than end date selected.

  }

});
```

Comment: This answer worked for me.  The accepted answer did not work.  Guess it depends on what version of datepicker perhaps?  Anyways, Thanks for this!

Answer (score 6):

The datepicker('setDate') sets the date in the datepicket not in the input.

You should add the date and set it in the input.

```
var date2 = $('.pickupDate').datepicker('getDate');
var nextDayDate = new Date();
nextDayDate.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
$('input').val(nextDayDate);
```

Comment: I had that before but when I used it it would only output like 'Sun Jan 17 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)' instead of '17-01-2010' even if I specified a dateformat option. Very odd. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @RichardReddy the output 'Sun Jan 17 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)' is right. `nextDayDate`holds a `Date`object, so when assigning to the input val a `toString` implicit conversion is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var today = new Date();
date = today.getDate() >= 10 ? `${today.getDate()}` : `0${today.getDate()}`;
month = today.getMonth()+1 >= 10 ? `${today.getMonth()+1}` : `0${today.getMonth()+1}`;
year = `${today.getFullYear()}`;
$('#datepicker_input_id').attr('value', `${month}/${date}/${year}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below. The code adds 15 days to datepicker and display in textbox named datepicker2 in format dd-mm-yy.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  inline: true,
  //altField: "#datepicker2",

  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var nextDayDate = new Date();
    nextDayDate.setDate(date.getDate() + 15);
    var copydate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', nextDayDate);
    $('#datepicker2').val(copydate);
  }
});
```