# Datepicker Jquery +1 day from chosen date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a script running on a Start Date and End Date, so when a user chooses the start date, the End Date is autofilled for them.

I am using the following, which populates the end date 1 day from Todays date, instead of 1 day from the start date.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#start").datepicker();
    $("#end").datepicker({

        onSelect: function(){
            var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#end").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime()));
            $("#end").datepicker("setDate", "+1d");

        }

    });

});
```

How would I get +1day on the chosen start date?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021788/how-to-add-a-day-to-a-date-using-jquery-datepicker?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

@K K , thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

This works perfect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#start").datepicker();
    $("#end").datepicker({

        onSelect: function(){
            var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#end").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime()));
            fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate()+1); 
            $("#end").datepicker("setDate", fecha);

        }

    });

});
```