# Bootstrap datepicker auto fill end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using the Bootstrap Datepicker [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in order to display a simple calendar range picker. All is working well so far, however I would like some additional functionality that I can't seem to figure out.

I would like to select a **start date** and then automatically fill in the **end date** (+10 days).

I'm sure this is possible however I can't figure it out.

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/o3k36Lg8/4/). Any help is greatly appreciated.

My **JS** is as follows;

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yy",
        startDate: "0d",
        endDate: "+10d",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        clearBtn: true,
        multidateSeparator: " ",
        forceParse: false,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
        orientation: "top auto",
        todayHighlight: true,
        toggleActive: true
    });
});
```

My **HTML** is as follows;

```
<div class="col-md-5" id="sandbox-container">

<h2>Select borrow date</h2> 
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="input-lg form-control" name="start" placeholder="borrow date" /> <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-lg form-control" name="end" placeholder="return date" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: visit this link..hope it may helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021788/how-to-add-a-day-to-a-date-using-jquery-datepicker]

Comment: thanks @TanyaSinha works now! If you change to answer I'll accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this link
[Datepicker using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021788/how-to-add-a-day-to-a-date-using-jquery-datepicker])

You have to include javascript on change fuction of first datepicker

```
 $('firstdatepicker').change(function() {
 var date2 = $('firstdatepicker').datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
 date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1); 
 $('seconddatepicker').datepicker('setDate', date2);
});
```