# Setting datepicker minimum date based on a previous date + 5

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

My application has two datepicker objects, and I would like to set the minimum date for the second object to be 5 days after the date selected for the first datepicker object.  Here is a snippet of code that I tried to use:

```
$( "#datePickerObj2" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", function() { var date2 = new Date();  date2 = $('#datePickerObj1').datepicker('getDate');  return date2.getDate()+5;});
```

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021788/how-to-add-a-day-to-a-date-using-jquery-datepicker) as help to write some of my code, but I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: date.getTime is not a function`.  Based on some research, this error pops up when the date variable isn't properly set as a date object, but I explicity handled that in my code, and I don't have an object just called "date".  Can anybody see my error?

**EDIT**:  Also, incase people point out that I didn't use the correct answer from the link, I also tried:

```
$( "#datePickerObj2" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", function() { var date2 = $('#datePickerObj1').datepicker('getDate');  var nextDayDate = new Date();  nextDayDate.setDate(date2.getDate() + 5); return nextDayDate;});
```

with the same issue.

Comment: The error I am getting is from `(typeof date === "number" ? (isNaN(date) ? defaultDate : offsetNumeric(date)) : new Date(date.getTime()))));`  in jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js

Answer (score 1):

The `minDate` option in the datepicker object should get the Date object, and not a function (like you send).
You can use this code:

```
var date2 = $('#datePickerObj1').datepicker('getDate');
var nextDayDate = new Date();
nextDayDate.setDate(date2.getDate() + 5);
$( "#datePickerObj2" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", nextDayDate);
```

If you really want this to be a one-liner you can write your function and call it in the same line:

```
$( "#datePickerObj2" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", (function() { var date2 = $('#datePickerObj1').datepicker('getDate');  var nextDayDate = new Date();  nextDayDate.setDate(date2.getDate() + 5); return nextDayDate;})());
```

I don't really like this approach, but you can use it :)

Comment: hmm, I'm still getting the error :/  Though you are right in that I should be passing the date option to the minDate.

Comment: Oh, you know what?  I just tried having the second datepicker object not be null on a whim, and it executed the code fine.  I don't know why this is though, as I am never reading the second datepicker object

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around to this issue, will post what I have done, thanks to Dekel for guiding me on this path!

```
var date2 = $('#datePickerObj1').datepicker('getDate');
var nextDayDate = new Date();
nextDayDate.setDate(date2.getDate() + 5);
$( '#datePickerObj2').datepicker("setDate", nextDayDate);
$( '#datePickerObj2').datepicker("option", "minDate", nextDayDate);
```

for some reason, since my second datepicker object wasn't selected yet, a `null` value was being passed somewhere, casuing type errors.  So I set the date for the second datepicker first, then I set it's min date as that date.