# Calculate and automaticly set value to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get some value and calculate it and set value to specific input field.

Here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3b51fts/) link

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select id="category" placeholder="Category" name="Category"></select>
        <script>
            $('#category').selectize({
                maxItems: null,
                valueField: 'id',
                labelField: 'title',
                searchField: 'title',
                options: [{
                    id: 'tiny',
                    title: 'Tiny'
                }, {
                    id: 'small',
                    title: 'Small'
                }, {
                    id: 'big',
                    title: 'Big'
                }],
                create: true
            });
        </script>
    </div>
<label for="price" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> </label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select id="price" placeholder="Price" name="price"></select>
        <script>
            $('#price').selectize({
                maxItems: null,
                valueField: 'id',
                labelField: 'title',
                searchField: 'title',
                options: [{
                    id: '8000',
                    title: '8000'
                }, {
                    id: '11000',
                    title: '11000'
                }, {
                    id: '13000',
                    title: '13000'
                }],
                create: true
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if user input tiny, the input field for price automaticly set value to 8000 and so on. And also for datepicker

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datecheckout" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date Checkout</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="test"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>

        </div>
        <script>
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                language: "id",
                forceParse: false,
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <label for="datearrive" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date Arrive</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>

        </div>
        <script>
            $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
                language: "id",
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

If it's tiny category, #datepicker2 plus 8 day to whatever value from #datepicker. If it's small category, #datepicker2 plus 10 day to whatever value from #datepicker, and so on. And yes i've been playing around with angularjs too but also dont know how to dynamically give some value to input field.

Please help, i appreciate your answer. Sorry for my english btw, i hope you can understand :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I completely understand what you are trying to do, but this can help you. On inputs, selects ... you can use the [JQuery change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) to act once the change, selection is done.

Here is a simple example:
When picked one element in the `select` box, the `input` gets updated with the selected value.

```
<select id='pick'>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select><br><br>

<input id='selected'/>
```

```
$('#pick').change( function() {
    $('#selected').val('YOU SELECTED: ' + $('#pick').val());
});
```

You can apply this on your example. <kbd>[See Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/x3b51fts/2/)</kbd>

**UPDATE**

This example is setting price value to '8000' if 'tiny' is selected in category:

```
$('#category').change( function() {
    var selected = $('#category').val();
    if(selected == 'tiny') {
        var selectize_tags = $("#price")[0].selectize;
        selectize_tags.setValue('8000');
    }
});
```

<kbd>[See Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/x3b51fts/4/)</kbd>

Comment: i'm using selectizejs plugin. After tried with jquery autocomplete http://jsfiddle.net/x3b51fts/3/ not work

Comment: This example sets the value of price to '8000' if 'tiny' is selected in category: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/x3b51fts/4/

Comment: awesome, but how to add plus 8 day from date checkout input and set the value to date arrive?

Comment: You can use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021788/how-to-add-a-day-to-a-date-using-jquery-datepicker#2022046