# jQuery Datepicker adding days

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

**Edit:** working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yao6dgex/

**Edit 2:** I think I know what's going on, but no reason why, it' getting the actual day and adding the days, instead of adding days from the selected date.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021788/how-to-add-a-day-to-a-date-using-jquery-datepicker) answer to my question, but it's not solving anything at all.

The problem is, that when I add X days, in the same calendar or another one, it's going to the next month in the X day.

My code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cal3").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#cal4").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
            $("#cal4").datepicker("setDate", "+3d");
            $("#cal4").datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $("#cal4").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#cal3").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

In this example, I added the selected date to `cal4` and then add 3 days from it.

Datepicker `setDate` API says:

> Sets the date for the datepicker. The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date format (e.g., "01/26/2009"), a number of days from today (e.g., +7) or a string of values and periods ("y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, "d" for days, e.g., "+1m +7d"), or null to clear the selected date.

I'm trying to add X days with `"+Xd"`, so, why it is not working?

Comment: have you tried with only "+X"

Comment: @vijayP yes, and it's doing the same

Comment: can its possible for you to create a working fiddle for this?

Comment: @vijayP added the fiddle on the top of the question

Comment: I think I know what's going on, but no reason why, it' getting the actual day and adding the days, instead of adding days in the selected date

Comment: i think your assessment is correct. Its better to add 3 days in first `setDate` statement only.

Comment: @vijayP the thing is, from the api resource, that if I only put "+Xd" it will add 3 days from today, not from a date given

Comment: yes..thats very true...:)!

Comment: @vijayP Hope this plugin have some function or something to do with it, otherwise, I'll have to get function around that calcs the days and add it (a bit more work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a simple workaround.
Instead of letting `datepicker` to manage the add days operation, we can do it with a `Date()` javascript object.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cal3").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            //$("#cal4").datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate"); //Get the Date object with actual date
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3); //Set date object adding 3 days.
            $("#cal4").datepicker("setDate", date); //Set the date of the datepicker with our date object
            $("#cal4").datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $("#cal4").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#cal3").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

I fork the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1jbq2m1/) with the answer code.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do a workaround as yours to get what I needed. At first I thought that the plugin would do the work with a selected date, but it seems it does not. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to be helpful. Looks reasonable that datepicker provide the desired functionality but it doesn't. If you need to this very often maybe you could try to add a new method on the plugin to do the desired operation.