# Adding days to Selected Date with jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have two 'Text boxes' and i am selecting date in 'Textbox1' with jquery Datepicker. When i selected the date in Textbox1,I need to display a date automatically in Textbox2 with adding two days to selected in Textbox1.

> For Example:  if selected Date in 'Textbox1' is '31/12/2015'
>
> Display Date in 'Textbox2' as 02/02/2016...

I need to add months and year also to be added and display in Textbox2.

Any Suggestions...........?

Comment: what you tried for that ?

Comment: Duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021788/how-to-add-a-day-to-a-date-using-jquery-datepicker

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what you have done so far and then ask a more specific question, that will make it much more likely to get an answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textbox1").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       var someDate=new Date(dateText);
       var duration =2; //day
       $("#textbox2").val(new Date(someDate.getTime() +  (duration * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to do the date additions, it is much cleaner than trying to do manual date additions in pure JS. see my codebase below to do what you have described in the question.

```js
$(function() {
debugger;
  $('#textbox1').datepicker(
  {
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var txtBox2 = $('#textbox2');
      var _sel = new moment(dateText);
      txtBox2.val(_sel.add('day',2));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1">
  <input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```